# how elevate a normal user to oracle user in cx_Oracle - Python

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I have an user: UserZXY and UserZXYPassword.
This user can execute "sudo su - oracle".
But, they no have a oracle password.

Is possible use a cx_oracle (python), connect in oracle database and elevate to oracle user to run a command?

Can you share an example?

Best regards.

Comment: Do you mean you want to access privileged tables and data inside the DB - see the cx_Oracle doc https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#privileged-connections?  Or do you mean you want to run operating system commands as the OS 'oracle' user?  That's not related to cx_Oracle, hence my confusion.